# Add key pair value to object if todays date is within a range using moment

Tags: javascript, object, momentjs

I have an object for an event below.

```
event: {
author: {id: 14738, first_name: "Test", last_name: "Test"},
departments_activities: [{…}],
start_at: "2022-10-11 13:00:00",
end_at: "2022-10-16 13:18:00",
id: 715437490
title: "test date 2"
}
```

I am looking to add an isToday (boolean) key pair value onto the array if the event is on today.
Obviously this will involve checking if the current date is between that start and end date but I'm struggling to find a solution that doesn't just set isToday to true if the current date is anywhere between the two start dates.

I've tried using

```
moment(moment()).isBetween(start_at, end_at)
```

and other iterations but that will return true if today is anywhere between the range of the start and end date.

Is this possible using moment or any other method?

Comment: FYI: the developers of [tag:momentjs] recommend that you do not use it.   See [SO wiki on moment](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/momentjs/info)

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't be my choice but it's a legacy project and it's not in the budget to update it all.

Comment: You need to pass the date you want to test into the `moment()` constructor, if you don't pass a date it uses `today`.   eg `isActive: moment(date_to_test).isBetween(start_at, end_at)`

Comment: TBH your requirement is a little unclear:  "*check if the current date is between start and end*" ... "*but [can't] find a solution that doesn't just set true if date is between start and end*".   Do you want to use "today's date" for *today* or not?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `moment`, here's a plain js solution:

```
let now = new Date()
let isBetween = now >= new Date(event.start_at) && now <= new Date(event.end_at)
```